# Inherited variables and methods in java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I feel that the output is straight `2 child 2` but it turns out to be `child 1 2`???

As parent is pointing to child the variables and methods from the child should be used but 1 is being printed after the string child. Why the string is printed before s.i? and why it is referring to the parent's copy of i?

here is my sample code:

```
public class Abc
{
  int i=1;
  public int getStr()
  {
    system.out.print("parent");
    return i;
  }
  public static void main(int[] a)
  {
    Abc s = new child();
    system.out.print(s.i + " " + s.getStr());
  }
}

class child
{
  int i=2;
  public int getStr()
  {
     system.out.print("child");
     return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid java e.g. `psv main()` `Class` `system.out.print()`. Give us runnable code.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example?

Comment: This code won't compile... dopes `child` extend `Abc`?

Comment: @Takendarkk psv == `public static void`

Comment: Which, sure enough, is not valid java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume here that you meant `child` to extend `Abc`, and that "psv" means `public static void`.  Also, I assume that `Class Abc` is really `class Abc` and that `system.out.print` is really `System.out.print` (capitalization issues).

In `main`, a new `child` is created and assigned to an `Abc` reference.  The JVM must evaluate the expression argument to `System.out.println` before passing it to the method.

`s.i` is statically resolved to `Abc`'s `i`, or `1` -- no polymorphism with variables, only methods.

The evaluation then calls `getStr()`.  The `child` class overrides `getStr()`, so it prints `child` first, and returns the `i` in scope -- `2`.

Back in `main`, the expression evaluation finishes -- `1` plus a space plus `2`. So, that expression is printed, immediately following the already printed `child`.

```
child1 2
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot...So you mean that method calls will be evaluated 1st and then the variables will be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that child does extend Abc, make one change.  Do not declare i in child, just inherit from Abc.  In other words, in child, change

```
int i=2;
```

to

```
i=2;
```

Note: you will need to put this inside the constructor.  What you are doing is shadowing which causes all sorts of confusion.  [This post provides a nice example, very close to your question.](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15)

Comment: Ummm... if you simply change it to `i = 2` it won't compile, because you now have a statement that isn't part of a method.

Comment: Put it in the constructor.  Its not like OP's code ever compiled.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue of where `"child"` appears in the output:  The call

```
System.out.print(s.i + " " + s.getStr());
```

is *not* the same as

```
System.out.print(s.i);
System.out.print(" ");
System.out.print(s.getStr());
```

In the first case, the program has to compute the *entire* output string first, before printing anything, by computing the three parts and creating one concatenated string.  Then it prints that.  It doesn't print the three parts one part at a time (the way the second example would).  So while it's computing the string, it calls `getStr()`, which will print `"child"` first.  That's why `"child"` appears in the output before `"1 2"`.